# After linking verb whether adjectives or adverbs

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, linking-verbs

I know after linking verb, Adjectives should be used, not adverbs. For  example **I'am fine (not well, as WELL is an adverb)**. But how you explain the following sentences ,

1. I'm abroad.
2. I'm home.
3. I'm upstairs.

Comment: In "I'm well", "well" is not an adverb but an adjective. It's an adverb in "Ed played well", where it modifies the verb "played". In your other examples, "abroad", "home" and "upstairs" are prepositions functioning as locative complement of "be".

Comment: As @BillJ points out, you're completely mistaken about ***I'm well***. But you might find [Examples of Linking Verbs](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-linking-verbs.html) useful.

Comment: If I say, next friday I will go abroad. Here abroad is an adverb, isn't it?@BillJ.

Comment: In traditional grammar, "abroad" is an adverb, but modern grammar analyses it as a preposition, meaning "to another country". [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/abroad).

Comment: *Abroad* can only be an adverb if it is acting to describe the method by which you are *going*. In this case, it doesn't. The action of *going* remains unchanged. It is acting to describe *where* you are going, not *how*. So, it's a preposition.